# The terminal shell path "..\..\..\vsCode\git\bin\bash.exe" does not exist in VS Code Windows

Tags: json, windows, visual-studio-code, relative-path

I am trying to set a portable development Environment:

VS Code - Portable mode
git-bash - portable
Node.js - portable

VS Code throws Error: The terminal shell path "......\vsCode\git\bin\bash.exe" does not exist

I have C:......\Documents\Storage\vsCode\data\user-data\User\settings.json
and    C:......\Documents\Storage\vsCode\git\bin\bash.exe

settings.json:

```
{
    // Git Bash
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "..\\..\\..\\vsCode\\git\\bin   \\bash.exe"
}
```

It works in CMD:

```
C:\.........>cd C:\...........\Documents\Storage\vsCode\data\user-data\User

C:\.......\Documents\Storage\vsCode\data\user-data\User>cd ..\..\..\git\bin\

C:\.......\Documents\Storage\vsCode\git\bin>
```

Can you guide me how to deal with relative path in VS Code without setting global variables in the operating system. I will need to do the same thing with Node.

Sorry for the messy post but I am fairly new to posting here.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow below link :
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

You need to edit the terminal integrated path in settings.json file to which ever thing you want it to compile it with

[image]

See the URL in the screenshot to find the location for settings.json file at my end:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I searched for "shell path" in the VS Code settings and noticed that the path was wrong
(**Program Files** instead of **Program Files (x86)**)

I had to change it to

```
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rhatalin thank you for the suggestion. I had the same issue on Windows 10. After updating below setting in settings.json (File -> Preferences -> Settings search for shell and choose Terminal-Integrated-Automation Shell: Windows -> Edit in settings.json) the issue was gone.

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

Comment: I  was looking for a relative path not absolute. for example if i have the VS code installed on a thumb drive which is E:\\portables\\VS code and Portable bash at E:\\portables\\Git, next time I move to another PC and have my drive letter changed I need to change the path. But if it is relative I only care about the portables directory in the tree not above.

Answer (score 0):

After a Windows update, I got the same error. I had to add escape \ characters to each backslash in the path to get it to work again. (check your path to make sure each single \ is double \)
This works: "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" 
This does not work: "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"

Comment: I think SO removed your double slashes

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use [environment variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables) in a settings.json, as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74460022/6309), you can use the new (Q3 2023) `GIT_SHELL_PATH` variable:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "${env:GIT_SHELL_PATH}"
```

With Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), add more "[`git var`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89d62d5e8ef42be3a73493e8ffbede589c7a31d1/Documentation/git-var.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var))</sup> for toolsmiths to learn various locations Git is configured with either via the configuration or hard-coded defaults.

See [commit ed773a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed773a18c6e92ae4f4e016f4529d6bdfbbbd56d8), [commit 576a37f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/576a37fccbf2a46d98a6dd367dbb3d1636e62f57), [commit 15780bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15780bb4f0cb07624ca6bac3c430ef07e9501663), [commit cdd489e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cdd489eaf9cd3c46c30b485601e2bcb989586274), [commit f74c90d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f74c90dcf7ed8ef7994ab583de089dba2a2b1a22), [commit 1e65721](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e6572122702cbf0e3b6d3226f73e6b8b45e6e37), [commit d6546af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6546af75c3cda2815f2e4d5322dd7a41cc0963b) (27 Jun 2023) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
See [commit 4db16f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4db16f58c7720257eea9ffb7d4e76809f2c403f0) (27 Jun 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 89d62d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89d62d5e8ef42be3a73493e8ffbede589c7a31d1), 04 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`var`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e6572122702cbf0e3b6d3226f73e6b8b45e6e37): add support for listing the shell
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> On most Unix systems, finding a suitable shell is easy: one simply uses "sh" with an appropriate PATH value.
> However, in many Windows environments, the shell is shipped alongside Git, and it may or may not be in `PATH`, even if Git is.
>
> In such an environment, it can be very helpful to query Git for the shell it's using, since other tools may want to use the same shell as well.
> To help them out, let's add a variable, `GIT_SHELL_PATH,` that points to the location of the shell.
>
> On Unix, we know our shell must be executable to be functional, so assume that the distributor has correctly configured their environment, and use that as a basic test.
> On Git for Windows, we know that our shell will be one of a few fixed values, all of which end in "`sh`" (such as "`bash`").
> This seems like it might be a nice test on Unix as well, since it is customary for all shells to end in "`sh`", but there probably exist such systems that don't have such a configuration, so be careful here not to break them.

`git var` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1e6572122702cbf0e3b6d3226f73e6b8b45e6e37/Documentation/git-var.txt#L74-L76):

> ### `GIT_SHELL_PATH`
>
> The path of the binary providing the POSIX shell for commands which use the shell.