# how to use environment variables in vscode settings json

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I want to be able to use linux environment variables in vscode workspace settings (specifically `$HOME`) so that I can specify paths that aren't specific to a user. In this case I am trying to set the `java.home` setting.

I have tried using `${env:HOME}` but this doesn't seem to work. I suspect this is only for vscode tasks.

```
{
    "java.home": "${env:HOME}/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.222.hs-adpt/"
}
```

Get the following error message at the moment:

> The java.home variable defined in VS Code settings points to a missing or inaccessible folder (${env:HOME}/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.222.hs-adpt/)

Comment: try just `"~/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.222.hs-adpt/"`

Comment: Unfortunately Tilda isn't recognised either

Comment: :( would think that would work. Seeing issues: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2809 env vars prob not supported yet (3+yr since issue opened) :(

Comment: Sad times, thanks for the thought though

Comment: It works for certain extensions if the author has coded the extension to handle the environment variables.

Answer (score 6):

Environment variables in Linux are supported now in VSCode (although I don't know since when or which version exactly). I have VSCode for Linux 1.73.1.

You can now use the following (just like in the question above):

```
{
    "java.home": "${env:HOME}/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.222.hs-adpt/"
}
```